# how do I specify a "maximum delta x" to pandas interpolation methods?

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
> print df
      C     B
A            
1   NaN     1
2   200   NaN
3   300     3
4   400   NaN
50  NaN  1000
```

I want to interpolate column B using `method='values'`. But I want NaNs if the delta X between consecutive rows exceeds a certain threshold. For example, if I specify a max delta x of 3, I'd expect something like this:

```
> print df
      C     B
A            
1   NaN     1
2   200     2
3   300     3
4   400   NaN
50  NaN  1000
```

Note how column B's value for row 4 remains NaN.

Comment: Hm. There's a neat way of exploiting the structure of the data if you know you have alternating values and NaN's in the desired column. is that the case? Is column B always value, NaN, value, Nan, (...) ?

Comment: Nope @vmg. I can't make that assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's what I came up with:

```
def interpolate_data_frame(df, column, max_delta_x=None):
    if max_delta_x is None:
        df[column] = df[column].interpolate(method='values')
        return df

    df['previous_x'] = (df['B'] / df['B'] * df.index).fillna(method='ffill')
    df['next_x'] = (df['B'] / df['B'] * df.index).fillna(method='bfill')
    df['delta_x'] = df['next_x'] - df['previous_x']
    df['valid'] = (df['delta_x'] < max_delta_x).map(lambda x: 1 if x else np.nan)
    df[column] = df[column].interpolate(method='values') * df['valid']
    del(df['previous_x'])
    del(df['next_x'])
    del(df['delta_x'])
    del(df['valid'])
    return df
```